# How to fetch fields in a view in the overrided twig file?

Tags: views, theming, 8

I have created a view like so:

[image]

I have written a twig file for it named 
`views-view--employee_details--block_1.html.twig`, which is placed in folder `/project_name/themes/theme_name/templates/views`.

I want to fetch fields from the view into 
`views-view--employee_details--block_1.html.twig` file.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
{{ fields.[machine_name].content }}
```

The [machine name](http://www.tenten71.com/drupal-theme-from-scratch/images/get-field-machine-name.png) is shown in your content type manage fields.

So it would be:

```
{{ fields.title.content }}
{{ fields.field_designation.content }}
```

Also, your template name needs to be: **`views-view-fields--employee-details--block-1.html.twig`**

Make sure you clear/flush the cache to see the changes.

Comment: {{ fields.title.content }}
{{ fields.field_designation.content }}
I have placed the above code in the twig file but still its not displaying.
Could you please let me know if there is any other way to print it?

Comment: @TanmayKadam see updated answer